# Handling exceptions in System.Reactive's Subscribe

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.reactive

I want to display the exceptions for all of the following subscriptions using `System.Reactive`.

A small piece of the code below, you can see what I tried, but it still doesn't display the message.

```cs
client.Streams.AggregateTradesStream
    .Subscribe(response =>
    {
        throw new Exception("Asd");

        Guard.Against.Null(response, nameof(response));
        Guard.Against.Null(response.Data, nameof(response.Data),
            "Something went wrong and the aggregated trade object is null");

        var trade = response.Data;
        Log.Information($"Aggregated trade [{trade.Symbol}] [{trade.Side}] " +
                        $"Price: {trade.Price} Size: {trade.Quantity}");
    }, ex => Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0} {1}", ex.Message, DateTime.Now))
    .DisposeWith(disposable);
```

How do I handle/display the exceptions for all of the `.Subscribe`s, because what I did, doesn't work? Perhaps, an extension method might be helpful.

### Full code

```cs
public class Program
{
    private static readonly ManualResetEvent ExitEvent = new(false);

    private static async Task Main()
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console(LogEventLevel.Debug, theme: SystemConsoleTheme.Colored)
            .WriteTo.File(Path.Combine("logs", "verbose.log"), rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
            .CreateLogger();

        var disposable = new CompositeDisposable();
        var uri = new Uri("wss://stream.binance.com:9443");

        using var communicator = new BinanceWebSocketCommunicator(uri);

        communicator.Name = "Binance-Spot";
        communicator.ReconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);

        communicator.ReconnectionHappened
            .Subscribe(info => Log.Information($"Reconnection happened, type: {info.Type}"))
            .DisposeWith(disposable);

        communicator.DisconnectionHappened
            .Subscribe(info => Log.Information($"Disconnection happened, type: {info.Type}"))
            .DisposeWith(disposable);

        using var client = new BinanceWebSocketClient(communicator);

        client.Streams.PongStream
            .Subscribe(x => Log.Information($"Pong received ({x.Message})"))
            .DisposeWith(disposable);

        client.Streams.AggregateTradesStream
            .Subscribe(response =>
            {
                throw new Exception("Asd");

                Guard.Against.Null(response, nameof(response));
                Guard.Against.Null(response.Data, nameof(response.Data),
                    "Something went wrong and the aggregated trade object is null");

                var trade = response.Data;
                Log.Information($"Aggregated trade [{trade.Symbol}] [{trade.Side}] " +
                                $"Price: {trade.Price} Size: {trade.Quantity}");
            }, ex => Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0} {1}", ex.Message, DateTime.Now))
            .DisposeWith(disposable);

        client.Streams.KlineStream
            .Subscribe(response =>
            {
                Guard.Against.Null(response, nameof(response));
                Guard.Against.Null(response.Data, nameof(response.Data),
                    "Something went wrong and the kline object is null");
                Guard.Against.Null(response.Data.Data, nameof(response.Data.Data),
                    "Something went wrong and the kline data object is null");

                var kline = response.Data;
                var klineData = response.Data.Data;

                Log.Information($"Kline [{kline.Symbol}] " +
                                $"Kline start time: {klineData.StartTime} " +
                                $"Kline close time: {klineData.CloseTime} " +
                                $"Interval: {klineData.Interval} " +
                                $"First trade ID: {klineData.FirstTradeId} " +
                                $"Last trade ID: {klineData.LastTradeId} " +
                                $"Open price: {klineData.OpenPrice} " +
                                $"Close price: {klineData.ClosePrice} " +
                                $"High price: {klineData.HighPrice} " +
                                $"Low price: {klineData.LowPrice} " +
                                $"Base asset volume: {klineData.BaseAssetVolume} " +
                                $"Number of trades: {klineData.NumberTrades} " +
                                $"Is this kline closed?: {klineData.IsClosed} " +
                                $"Quote asset volume: {klineData.QuoteAssetVolume} " +
                                $"Taker buy base: {klineData.TakerBuyBaseAssetVolume} " +
                                $"Taker buy quote: {klineData.TakerBuyQuoteAssetVolume} " +
                                $"Ignore: {klineData.Ignore} ");
            })
            .DisposeWith(disposable);

        client.AddSubscription(
            new AggregateTradeSubscription("bnbusdt"),
            new KlineSubscription("btcusdt", "1h"));

        await communicator.Start().ConfigureAwait(false);

        ExitEvent.WaitOne();

        disposable.Dispose();

        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that in order to display the exception in `.Subscribe`, I had to wrap it in a `.Select`/`.SelectMany` or `try catch` block.

```cs
client.Streams.AggregateTradesStream
    .Subscribe(response =>
    {
        try
        {
            Guard.Against.Null(response, nameof(response));
            Guard.Against.Null(response.Data, nameof(response.Data));

            var trade = response.Data;
            Log.Information($"Aggregated trade [{trade.Symbol}] [{trade.Side}] " +
                            $"Price: {trade.Price} Size: {trade.Quantity}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError(ex, "Exception while receiving message");
        }
    })
    .DisposeWith(disposable);
```